# I want to construct a query using the orderby clause. Please advise

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by, hierarchy

My data looks like this:

```
App ID  Ref Id  App Type  Reg Date
1       1       Main      2017-05-13
2       2       Sub       2017-05-14
3       1       Sub       2017-05-16
4       2       Main      2017-05-15
5       3       Main      2017-05-14
6       1       sub       2017-05-17
```

I would like to change this table as shown below.

```
App ID  Ref Id  App Type Reg Date
4       2       Main     2017-05-15
2       2       Sub      2017-05-14
5       3       Main     2017-05-14
1       1       Main     2017-05-13
6       1       sub      2017-05-17
3       1       Sub      2017-05-16
```

The contents with the same ref ID are displayed, and the content with the Main is positioned at the top.
The most recently registered content must be at the top.
That is, I want to create a hierarchy.

```
Select * 
from table 
order by refId desc, App Type asc, Reg Date desc
```

Should I configure the query like above?

Comment: The "order" is not clear: none of the columns is neither ascending nor descending.

Comment: Select *
from table
order by refId desc, Ref_ID, App Type asc, Reg Date desc

Comment: @uSeruSher Are you saying that both Ref_ID and App Type are sorted by asc?

Comment: @YoungHoLee from your output example, it looks like you want "Sub" after "Main" for same refid, in that case you will have to add refid to sort list too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tested it:

```
SELECT * 
FROM t 
JOIN (SELECT `Ref Id`, MAX(`Reg Date`) AS maxdate FROM t WHERE `App Type` = 'Main' GROUP BY 1) md USING(`Ref Id`) 
ORDER BY maxdate DESC, `Ref Id`, (`App Type` = 'Main') DESC;

+--------+--------+----------+------------+------------+
| Ref Id | App ID | App Type | Reg Date   | maxdate    |
+--------+--------+----------+------------+------------+
|      2 |      4 | Main     | 2017-05-15 | 2017-05-15 |
|      2 |      2 | Sub      | 2017-05-14 | 2017-05-15 |
|      3 |      5 | Main     | 2017-05-14 | 2017-05-14 |
|      1 |      1 | Main     | 2017-05-13 | 2017-05-13 |
|      1 |      6 | sub      | 2017-05-17 | 2017-05-13 |
|      1 |      3 | Sub      | 2017-05-16 | 2017-05-13 |
+--------+--------+----------+------------+------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want:

```
select t.*
from t
order by (select max(t2.regdate) from t t2 where t2.refid = t.refid) desc,
         t.refid,
         (t.apptype = 'Main') desc,
         t.regdate desc;
```